# Selenium Python installation issue

Tags: python, selenium

I have followed the instruction from the site: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

I followed the section : Detailed instructions for Windows users:

completed step-1- by downloading and installing it (python-2.7.3.msi) to my windows . Now i got confuesd about the 2nd step. What i need to i can't understand ,i just downloaded the "pypa-virtualenv-1.8.1-74-g2adac08.tar.gz" and unzipped it to the folder "D:\Python and Selenium". Both the step-1 mentioned MSI .exe file and this .zip file present in the same directory as I just mentioned.

I also tried the below ,but got errors:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    C:\Users\Arup Rakshit>cd..

    C:\Users>cd..

    C:\>d:

    D:\>cd D:\Python and Selenium\pypa-virtualenv-2adac08

    D:\Python and Selenium\pypa-virtualenv-2adac08>pip install https://github.com/py
   pa/virtualenv/tarball/develop
   'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

    D:\Python and Selenium\pypa-virtualenv-2adac08>
```

Can you now guide me to install it on my PC succesfully?

***UPDATE***

```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
  Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  C:\Users\Arup Rakshit>cd..

  C:\Users>cd..

  C:\>cd Python27

  C:\Python27>cd python.exe
 The directory name is invalid.

 C:\Python27>python.exe virtualenv.py selenv
  python.exe: can't open file 'virtualenv.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory


 C:\Python27>
 C:\Python27>
```

Comment: Seems you didn't install pip or it is not in your PATH.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: a lots of conversion is there went on.. so can you brief me in my case what should i do? I just python-2.7.3.msi downloaded and installed it running the .exe file and .zip file has been downloaded and kept in the description mentioned directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have this file in your folder:

[virtualenv.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py)

And then with the command line run:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe virtualenv.py selenv
```

After that you will have a subfolder named "selenv".
With the command line run :

```
selenv\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium
```

And check if you can run your python-selenium scripts with 
    selenv\Scripts\python.exe my_selenium_script.py

Note that you need to use the full path to pip , since you do not have it in the windows PATH

Comment: In this folder- "D:\Python and Selenium" i have "python-2.7.3.msi" and "pypa-virtualenv-2adac08" folder. And within the folder i have the "setup.py" and "virtualenv.py" .

Comment: please confirm in which folder you want me to put the "virtualenv.py" file?

Comment: Yes it is Done!! Thank you very much!!Suarez... :-)

Comment: awesome, glad I could help . Sorry that I did not answer before to help with your comments, I was not at the computer.

Comment: Can you help me in my below post by giving any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887819/webpage-filed-level-details-data-extraction-and-saving-it-to-excel-using-seleniu#comment19132775_13887819

Comment: @TheMiddleMan I have updated the documentation based on your feedback.  Please let me know if any other suggestion.