# Selenium Install - What is meant by 'use pip command below to install selenium"?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, installation, selenium-webdriver

[This blog details the steps to installing Selenium for use with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). I don't understand what he means by "use pip command below to install selenium"?

```
C:\seltests\selenv\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium
```

There's no pip.exe in that folder. Do I have to use [this stackoverflow to install pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)?

baijum, if you're reading this, please clarify this part on your blog. Others on my team are not seeing pip.exe in the Scripts folder either!

I found this [stackoverflow article where the previous step was unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891996/selenium-python-installation-issue) but this article doesn't address the missing pip.exe issue.

Comment: That's not a blog. It's the documentation for the package. I would just run `easy_install pip` and then `pip install selenium` (assuming Python is correctly added to your PATH).

Comment: I used this [pip win tool](https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows). Is this an appropriate alternative to easy_install? I found it from this [popular pip Python article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Comment: It replaces `easy_install`.

Comment: Ok I ran the pip win tool with this command: pip install -U selenium. How do I test to make sure this worked?

Comment: It did not work. I ran the following: C:\seltests\selenv\Scripts\python.exe C:\seltests\my_selenium_script.py command and got ImportError: No module named selenium

Comment: Then you didn't install Selenium. Run pip from a shell and see what errors you get.

Comment: I didn't install pip. I'll try this now using the first post with 222 points in [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Comment: I'm stuck at this part: "For me, this installed Pip at C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe. Add your analogue of C:\Python27\Scripts to your path (Start / Edit environment variables). Now you should be able to run pip from the command line. Try installing a package:" What do they mean by "add your analogue of C:\Python27\Scripts to your path"?

Comment: See this: http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#configuring-python. Just add `;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts` to the `PATH` variable and you'll be able to run the scripts from a command prompt.

Comment: [Posting this Windows 7 article on environment variables to help others](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html).

Comment: Ugh. I get this in CMD prompt when I try to run pip.exe install selenium. "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in c:\python27\lib\site-packages Cleaning up..."

Comment: Same ImportError: No module named selenium when I tried to run a simple .py script.

Comment: [How does this make any sense - img of both errors?](http://imgur.com/YXYsgU1)

Comment: What does `where python` output? Are you actually running Python 2.7?

Comment: I figured it out. My scripts were not in the same folder structure to which I installed Selenium. I installed easy_install, pip and then selenium in the Python27 folder structure. I should have been running my scripts from there, rather than from the seltests folder structure. The selenium-python documentation really needs to clarify how to install pip correctly. That would have helped a lot instead of just saying C:\seltests\selenv\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium.